# How to calculate average?

Tags: education, average

I did visit the website of ministry of justice for my country , they are showing indicators for real estate transactions and one of them is the average of price per square meter in a neighborhood.

Example for transactions happened on a neighborhood:

Transaction 1 : **1,500,000** - on parcel with area : **900**  > price per square meter = 1,500,000/900 = **1666.67**
Transaction 2 : **950,000**  - on parcel with area : **600** > price per square meter = 950,000/600 = **1583.34**
Transaction 3 : **1,250,000** - on parcel with area : **850** > price per square meter = 1,250,000/850 = **1470.5**

In the website they did calculate the average as the following:

sum of all transactions total price / sum of all parcels area
1,500,000+950,000+1,250,000 / 900+600+850 = 1574.4

My question why it's not calculated like this :

Sum of all price per square meter / number of transactions
1666.67 + 1583.34 + 1470.5 / 3 = 1573.5

I know the difference is 1 but some times when number of transaction above 500 not just 3 it will make huge difference between them .

Which one is correct ? why ?

Comment: The formula you quote has the effect of weighting the price per unit of area by the area, which means the result is not affected by whether a single large plot is sold in a single transaction or in many small parts

Comment: One example would be, let's say you sold 100 toys for \$10 each and your friend sold 1 toy for \$100. Would it be more accurate to say the average toy sold for \$10.89 or for \$55?

Comment: @turkeyhundt thank you guys

Comment: @Henry thank you